# Using parameterized functions c++

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

say I have a C++ function

```
int foo(int x, int y){
   return x+y ;
}
```

Is there a way to create a "parameterized" version of this function?

What I mean is that starting from foo() I would like to define function pointers that have y fixed to a specific values, the equivalent of creating the function foo2() like this:

```
int foo2(int x){
  return foo(x,2);
}
```

If not with function pointers, which can be an alternative to have a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix (or *[curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)*) function arguments using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

For example, `foo2` could be

```
auto foo2 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, 2);
```

You could read this as:

A call to `foo2` is like a call to `foo` where the first argument is the first argument to the `foo2` call and the second argument is `2`.

The could be done with a lambda function:

```
auto foo2 = [] (int x) { return foo(x, 2); }
```

**[See the above in action](http://ideone.com/d2JPi)**.

Finally, if you cannot use C++11 then there's the equivalent [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Comment: Thanks. So what I am looking for is called "binding" in programming? Also, I would like to avoid boost libraries. 
To your knowledge does g++ with -std=c+11 flag support binding?

Comment: @LucaCerone: Binding is one term that you can use, but "fixing arguments" and "currying" are better if you are searching for it. g++ supports C++11, so it does support these solutions (I 've added a link to live code).

Comment: Thanks Jon, unfortunately my compiler doesn't support C++11 yet.
(It's gcc 4.6, c++11 support has been introduced in 4.7.. I'll try to update, but I don't want to risk that my older program have problems...)

Comment: @LucaCerone: For C++03 the simplest solution is to use `boost::bind`, which uses almost exactly the same syntax (you will need to specify the type of the return value -- use `boost::function<int(int)>` as the type and see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html) for more info). Alternatively you can use standard C++03 syntax as per tozka's answer, but that works only for simple cases and is a little bit less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the function with

```
int foo(int x) {
    return foo(x,2);
}
```

and you will have the same name... or the default argument solution...

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers do not support anything of the sort. In fact, all they *do* support is pointing to static functions. Don't ever use them for callbacks, use `std::function` instead or a template.

You can use `std::bind` or a lambda to achieve this goal. But you won't get out a function pointer, only a function object, which you can use through the proper abstraction (template or `std::function`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::bind for instance:

```
std::bind2nd (std::ptr_fun (foo), arg2) (arg1) // replace second argument
std::bind1st (std::ptr_fun (foo), arg1) (arg2) // replace/bind first argument
```

you can also assign it to variable:

```
auto fun = std::bind1st (std::ptr_fun (foo), 2);
auto fun = std::bind2nd (std::ptr_fun (foo), 2);
```

or if your compiler does not support C++11

```
typedef std::binder1st<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, int, int>> fun_type;
fun_type fun = std::bind1st (std::ptr_fun (foo), 2); // foo (2, arg2);


typedef std::binder2nd<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, int, int>> fun_type2;
fun_type2 fun = std::bind2nd (std::ptr_fun (foo), 2); // foo (arg1, 2);
```

and then call it

```
fun (arg);
```

Comment: thanks @tozka, I find your answer a bit hard to follow, though I could get the general idea..